# Cherry-pick section of commits from one branch to another, for specific folder

Tags: git

I read few answers regard cherry-pick but couldn't found exactly what am I looking for.
I work on a local branch of very large project.
My work is under a specific folder lets say LargProj/MyFolder.
While Master branch is update each day in many places, I am working on my local branch and once in few weeks I want to takes all the new commit from master, to my branch.

When I use cherry-pick MasterCommitHashStart..MasterCommitHashEnd There are a lot of conflicts on files and folder I don't care about.

How can I cherry-pick only the changes relevant to MyFolder between MainHashStart..MainHashEnd?

Thanks alot

Comment: "I read few answers regard cherry-pick but couldn't found exactly what am I looking for." Probably because cherry pick is _not_ what you're looking for. Do you know what an xy question is?  https://xyproblem.info/ Ask how to do a thing, not how to do it using a wrong approach.

Comment: There is enough explanation on what I want to achieve so experts who want to give direction can easily asnwer "don't use cherry-pick, use XYZ"

Comment: @eftshift0 yes probably but is there a way to rebase only under specific folder?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I cherry-pick only the changes relevant to MyFolder between MainHashStart..MainHashEnd

You can't. Git isn't about "changes" or "folders". It's about *commits*. A commit is basically a complete snapshot of the state of the entire working tree of the project at a moment in time. The only thing you can cherry pick is a commit.

You can, however, create a patch, edit it, and apply the edited patch.

Or (what I would do) just use `git restore` to extract the desired state of the particular individual files from the target commit into the working tree and make a new commit.

Comment: Isn't git cherry-pick <commitHash> takes the diff between commitHash^..commitHash
and does something like git apply on that diff?